# Inserting item into a linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to add to my linked list only if the item I'm inserting isn't already in the link list but when I try to traverse it and print out all of the items nothing is printing out. I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated

```
// my add function
void add(char *val)
{    
    printf("%s", val);// val is getting printed so i know its being passed in.
    if(head == NULL){
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        head = new_node;
        head->item = val;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else{
        struct node *current = head;
        struct node *newNode = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (newNode == NULL) {
            exit(-1);
        }        
        newNode->item = val;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        while (current != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }    
        current = newNode;
    }
}   

//my traverse function
void goThroughList() {
    struct node *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",current->item);
        current= current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`add` doesn't successfully add anything once `head` has been assigned.  It only updates a local `current` pointer.  You could fix that by changing the code that searches for the tail of the list to

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
current->next = newNode;
```

If this doesn't help, can you update your question to show how `add` is being called?  (To rule out the possibility that the same `char` array is being used for multiple calls, leaving all `node`s with their `item` pointers pointed to the same buffer.

Also, there is no code I can see that checks for duplicates.  You could implement this inside the branch of `add` where `head` already existed by iterating through the list using `strcmp` to compare each node's `item` with `val`.

Answer (score 1):

your `add` function is incorrect

try this one :

```
void add(char *val)
{    
    printf("%s", val);// val is getting printed so i know its being passed in.

    if(head == NULL){     
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->item = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;   
        head = new_node;
    } 
    else{
        struct node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(current->item, val) == 0)
          return;
        current = current->next;
        }
        struct node *new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->item = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        current->next = new_node;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Are you deliberately comparing string pointers rather than string content?  (i.e. should `if(current->item == val)` be `if(strcmp(current->item, val) == 0)`?)  Terminating the process when duplicates are added seems rather severe; cleaning up `new_node` then returning would seem better.

Comment: Its better.  The OP didn't specify behaviour if duplicates are added so I can't say that calling `exit` is incorrect.  I still think that terminating the process would be an over-reaction to what may well be an expected runtime condition.  I'd have made `add` return a boolean and returned `false` in this case to signal that nothing was added.  +1 anyway since the main bug from the question is fixed by your answer.

Comment: thanq soo much for letting me know my mistakes @simonc. I've changed `exit` to `return` . So is it ok now ??

Comment: Looks much better - thanks :).  And really +1 this time (apologies that I didn't upvote after my last comment)

Answer (score 0):

what list does this function go trought ?

```
void goThroughList() {
    struct node *current = head;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",current->item);
        current= current->next;
    }
}
```

try this instead :

```
void goThroughList(struct node* llist) 
{
      if(llist)
      {
         printf("%s" , llist->item);
          goThroughList(llist->next);
      }
}
```